# Handling XmlParsing in a different Thread Android

Tags: android, multithreading, xml-parsing, android-handler

I'm developing an app where I have to parse data from an XML in a URL. My parser is now running and showing me the data, but the problem I'm having is that I'm unable to handle properly the process of parsing the data. My app is divided by fragments and each fragment will display some info. I'm doing all the parsing/http connection from one fragment. Right now the app does not display the data, I'm using Log.d to display the results, but when the data is showing on the logcat, the app is like frozen or in pause. This is the method that makes the connection to the URL of the xml:

```
     public void loadXML(){
    Thread thread=new Thread(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        try{
            URL url=new URL(FEED_URL);
            HttpURLConnection conn=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(1000);/*miliseconds*/
            conn.setConnectTimeout(1500);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.connect();
            InputStream stream=conn.getInputStream();
            XmlPullParserFactory factory=XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();    /*Instantiate new parser*/
            XmlPullParser xmlParser=factory.newPullParser();
            xmlParser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
            xmlParser.setInput(stream,null);
            items=(ArrayList<Item>) XmlFeedParser.parser(xmlParser);//the method that does the parsing
            stream.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
thread.start();
}
```

As far as I know I have to use a Handler, but I only have this line

```
  private Handler handler = new Handler(){
```

in the Fragment class,  I call the loadXML() method in onStart() of my fragment. Besides from the Thread shown in the code, I'm not creating any other thread or calling any other method. 
Any help or information will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

did you try calling getActivity().runOnUiThread(action) ?

Comment: I haven't checked if I can use this method, I'm checking it right now, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would read through this android developer page on [Parsing XML Data](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html). I think the example there is exactly what you are looking for.